# Jpeg 2000 Grayscale support in GAE ImagesService

Tags: google-app-engine

We just ran into a problem when we tried to upload some JPEG2000 Grayscale images to Google Appengine and tried to process them using ImagesService. The error from production is:

> > > com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFailureException: at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:284)

According to GAE ImagesService:

> > > The service accepts image data in the JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated GIF), BMP, TIFF and ICO formats.

My question is how we can configure ImagesService to server Jpeg2000 grayscale images, rather than recompress already compressed images to supported format before uploading them to GAE. Repeat compression will damage image quality greatly!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the list of supported formats.

It would probably be a good idea if you file a feature request in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). We can then triage the request and gauge the demand for it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue tracker link, I will put the request there. regards!